# How to achieve disorganised bubble layout with html css?

Tags: html, css

I need to have a bubble layout like this:

[image]

I have completed the work till this stage - [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/huyasi/6)

As I am not that skilled in CSS/Web design, I can only think of using table tr td.
But I can see I will need the bubbles to be aligned close to each other. If I go for table structure, I dont think it will work.

Please suggest some design structure, or I should go for other things, SVG, etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps you :) I have fun with this.
(Also check out this for some great reading / viewing http://paulbourke.net/texture_colour/randomtile/)

Demo: http://po0.co.uk/circles/

Uses: http://packery.metafizzy.co/

Code:

```
<style>
    .circle
    {
    border-radius:50%;
    text-align:center;
    background:#efdeee;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:-5px;
    }
</style>
<div id="container">
    <?php
    $xx = 1;
    while ($xx <= 200) {
        $thisx = rand(10,99);
        echo '<div class="item circle" style="width:'.$thisx.'px;height:'.$thisx.'px;">&nbsp;</div>';
        $xx++;
    }
    ?>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/packery/1.4.1/packery.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var container = document.querySelector('#container');
    var pckry = new Packery( container, {
      // options
      itemSelector: '.item',
      gutter: 10
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Resize the browser window for extra fun :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with the HTML5 canvas feature. [Here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com) you can learn more about CANVAS.

Please visit the [FiddleDemo](https://jsfiddle.net/mkp11xdk/4/).

**HTML**

```
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="circles"></canvas>
```

**Javascript**

```
var circle = $('#circles').get(0).getContext('2d');

var circles = [
    { x:  50, y:  50, r: 25, c: "#78BA00" },
    { x: 80, y:  100, r: 35, c: "#F4B300" },
    { x: 150, y: 170, r: 15, c: "#78BA00" },
    { x:  50, y: 220, r: 20, c: "#F4B300" },
    { x:  60, y: 150, r: 10, c: "#78BA00" },
    { x: 70, y: 170, r: 15, c: "#F4B300" },
    { x:  110, y: 220, r: 16, c: "#78BA00" },
    { x:  130, y: 150, r: 2, c: "#F4B300" },
    { x:  60, y: 150, r: 5, c: "#78BA00" },
    { x: 70, y: 170, r: 12, c: "#F4B300" },
    { x:  110, y: 30, r: 21, c: "#78BA00" },
    { x:  180, y: 60, r: 2, c: "#F4B300" },    
    { x:  70, y: 90, r: 21, c: "#78BA00" },
    { x:  220, y: 110, r: 2, c: "#F4B300" }
];

function drawCircle(data) {
    circle.beginPath();
    circle.arc(data.x, data.y, data.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    circle.fillStyle = data.c;
    circle.fill();
}

$.each(circles, function() {
    drawCircle(this);

});
```

Explanation of **{ x:  50, y:  50, r: 25, c: "#78BA00" },**

- x : x-axis postion in pixels
- y : y-axis position in pixels
- r : radius in pixels
- c : mention the color in hex

**With the help of above parameters you can Position, Size and Color the circles as per your needs.**

Most importantly this solution will be independent of server-side scripting.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.. but the point is i need many bubbles just like in the image

Comment: For that purpose you will need to write **CSS** for generating the circles and **jQuery** for multiplying those with dynamic parameters.

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can achive the required circles with the help of HTML5 canvas as well. This way you will much better control on Position + Size + Color of each and every circle.