# Masonry layout using different sized circular elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a design layout that uses **different** circle sized elements, which are grouped together to fill in the space in-between. It's exactly like the Apple Watch home app layout, but in addition, the circles have different sizes.

The design team got the inspiration from the team section in this website: https://www.fcinq.com/. I spent a few hours trying to find a library that can do this, or some open-sourced code. It seems like this was custom written.

I cannot use D3 or any library that creates the elements in SVG format, because I need to implement custom click events with JS on some of the elements. Basically, I want to avoid a huge library if possible.

Does anyone know of any library that can do this out-of-the-box? Or if there's something I can use that would help me or guide me to get this done? I'm limited with the timeframe and your help would be much appreciated.

Anything would help as long as it can achieve the same as https://masonry.desandro.com/ but with Circle elements that fill in the gaps (circles attract each other so that different sized ones don't leave huge white gaps between one another).

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What do you mean by 'fill in the gaps'?

Comment: Hey Billy, sorry for not being clear. I meant that the circles attract each other so that different sized ones don't leave huge white gaps between one another. This website has the best example: https://www.fcinq.com/. It's actually very similar to what I want to achieve.

Comment: Are you talking about this bubbles grid? http://design-mania.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/28-fcinq-2.jpg

Comment: Hi @jigneshRaval, yes exactly that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I managed to implement for those who might have the same question:

With the help of Jignesh, I managed to ask the right question to my own problem, and I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31098961/11498451

It uses Packery library (https://packery.metafizzy.co/) to achieve filling the extra gaps. I added a few Stamp elements (https://packery.metafizzy.co/methods.html#stamp) on the corners of the container to achieve the circular/centred feel since it's not offered by default from the library.

**EDIT:** Here's a working example: https://codepen.io/owenfar/pen/xxbybyX

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="stamp corner-tl"></div>
  <div class="stamp corner-tr"></div>

  <div class="item circle" style="width: 26px; height: 26px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 142px; height: 142px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 67px; height: 67px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 47px; height: 47px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 152px; height: 152px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 105px; height: 105px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 138px; height: 138px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 132px; height: 132px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 165px; height: 165px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 83px; height: 83px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 136px; height: 136px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 160px; height: 160px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 139px; height: 139px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 60px; height: 60px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 97px; height: 97px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 70px; height: 70px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 34px; height: 34px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 64px; height: 64px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 136px; height: 136px;"></div>
  <div class="item circle" style="width: 27px; height: 27px;"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/packery/1.4.1/packery.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<style>
.circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background: teal;
    display: inline-block;
}

.stamp {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;

  &.corner-tl {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  &.corner-tr {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
</style>

<script>
var container = document.querySelector('#container');
var pckry = new Packery ( container, {
    // Options
    itemSelector: '.item',
    gutter: 5,
    stamp: '.stamp',
});
</script
```

Hope that helps.

Thanks to those who looked into my question.

Comment: Hi @OwenFar, I am really glad that you found the exact thing you were looking for. If possible for you, then can you please share a small and simple working bubble grid example that it will be a really great help for me and others. Thank you.